# Wordpress: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined, contact-form-7

### I updated a Contact-Form-7 plugin on my Wordpress site, and now am getting this error:

*Notice: Undefined index: contact-form-7 in /home/kilowa5/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 250*

*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/kilowa5/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 250*

Here are lines 241-258 of the class.wp-scripts.php file:

```
}

/**
 * @param string $handle    Name of the item. Should be unique.
 * @param bool   $recursion Internal flag that calling function was called recursively.
 * @param mixed  $group     Group level.
 * @return bool Not already in the group or a lower group
 */
public function set_group( $handle, $recursion, $group = false ) {
    if ( $this->registered[$handle]->args === 1 )
        $grp = 1;
    else
        $grp = (int) $this->get_data( $handle, 'group' );

    if ( false !== $group && $grp > $group )
        $grp = $group;

    return parent::set_group( $handle, $recursion, $grp );
```

Line 250 is `if ( $this->registered[$handle]->args === 1 )`

Comment: Show the code that you updated and the one producing errors.

Comment: @deadbeef I edited my post with code from the .php file my error is referencing. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `Undefined index: contact-form-7` which is `$handle` does not exist as a key in `$this->registered` array. Then, `Trying to get property of non-object` because `$this->registered[$handle]` is null and you're trying to access to `args` field of a null object

Comment: Justin, thank you for diagnosing this.
I don't know code, but am not afraid to go in and edit a file on our server if someone tells me what to do. (Which file, what code to add/delete, from where, etc.)Based on what you're seeing, what edits should I make to this code?

Comment: Any progress? Experiencing the same error here...